# setState Before Route Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-16

I have an `authentication` state that I use through the `Provider`/`Consumer` context API in React 16.

I initially set the state of this property in my main `App` to `false` and then for any restricted components (i.e. that require being authenticated) I make a query to the backend to check if the current token on the client-side is valid.

Thus, I want `authentication` to always be consumed as `false` initially by any components when users change browser URLs.

How can I reset `authentication` on each route change? I am listening on `history.listen` but if I call `setState` there is no guarantee that `authentication` will get set to the `false` state before the component initially renders.

Comment: Novice developer here. I just wonder why do you want to use authentication logic like this. What is the use case?

Comment: Was just trying to use the Context API and setup my own authentication without using redux.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get the "change with route part". Why do you want to reset auth state in url changes?

Comment: If I don't and assume they are authenticated then they may access a page even though their client-side token is actually expired on the server side.

Comment: Not to mention it wouldn't be a great user experience if they saw the page for a split second before being redirected to the authentication page.

Comment: Ok, some sort of simple session mechanism?